# Disable Button Shift in BorderPane

Tags: java, javafx

I have a BorderPane on which is located a Label and a HBox with two buttons. BorderPane is a single table cell.

```
BorderPane cellView = new BorderPane();
HBox hBox = new HBox();
hBox.getChildren().add(expandButton);
hBox.getChildren().add(new OpenTagTreeSelectionDialogButton(this::updateProperty));
cellView.setRight(hBox);
cellView.setLeft(new Label(value));
setGraphic(cellView);
```

[image]

When I enter too large a text, my buttons move and disappear from view.

[image]

Please tell me how to make it so that you can enter text of any length and at the same time the buttons are not shifted, but just were on top of this text

Comment: Try setting the max-width of each `Label`. Creating your own "table-cell" is probably a bad idea unless you are an advanced programmer.  Your table probably lacks virtualization. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/javafx/scene/control/skin/VirtualFlow.html

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand the source code because of it is not complete

I see a table

I see the buttons are inside the cell
I think you need to put the button outside(create new cell and put them.

other idea
i see that you have same button, if they have same work so put it outside the table(next to the +, - and ^ button for example) or any other place

Comment: BorderPane is a single table cell.